# C# datagridview. Cell backcolor is empty dispite of DefaultCellStyle

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, colors, background

I set the cell background color in a datagridview to yellow via

```
`grid.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Yellow;`
```

I see the yellow cells but should the back color property of the cell not also be yellow? I get an "Color[Empty]" instead of color yellow. Why is the color not Yellow if I try the following code? 
    `grid.CellClick += new DataGridViewCellEventHandler(
                (eventsource, cellevent) =>
                {
                      int rowIndex = cellevent.RowIndex;
                      int colIndex = cellevent.ColumnIndex;
MessageBox.Show(" color: "+ grid.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[colIndex].Style.BackColor);
});`

Comment: Sorry. I mean Winforms

Comment: Have you resolved your problems?

Answer (score 3):

> should the back color property of the cell not also be yellow?

No, it should not.

Note that you can set each cell's `BackColor` individually to some other color that the default color. When it is set it takes **precedence** over the default. `Color.Emtpy` is an **extra** values that means: `display the default color`.

[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.color.empty(v=vs.110).aspx):

> Color Empty   :       Specifies whether this Color structure is uninitialized.

To find out what is displayed you can simply test for it:

```
Color c = someCell.Style.BackColor == Color.Emtpy ? 
          dgv.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor: someCell.Style.BackColor;
```

Another way to test is the [`color.IsEmpty`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.color.isempty(v=vs.110).aspx) function.

And you can also **reset** a color you have set to the default color by setting it to `Color.Emtpy`. And when the default color changes it will change also.

**Example**:

You want to mark cell with issues with a rosy back color. The default color is light gray until user enters edit mode; then is changes to white.

The rosy cells will not follow because they have an individual color set.

After correcting the issue the user leaves the cell and you reset its color: But not to white but to `Color.Empty`.

Now when the user leaves edit mode all cells without issues turn back to the default browse color light gray..

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. So initialy the default value is taken if cell background is not set (Color.Empty) otherwise (i.e. if individual color is set for cell) the color which is set is shown (higher priority).

Comment: Exactly. Makes for a flexible display.