# How to keep DataGridView cell forecolor when it is selected

Tags: c#, visual-studio, datagridview

I have a `DataGridView` which displays some values in red and some in blue, depending on certain conditions. However, when a row is selected, the backcolor of that row is changed (that's fine, I actually need that) but also the forecolor of all the cells in that row, which ruins everything.

Is that a way to change only the backcolor of the selected row, keeping each cell forecolor as it were before selection?

Comment: [DataGridView.CellFormatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellformatting?view=netcore-3.1)

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50213063/c-sharp-datagridview-cell-backcolor-is-empty-dispite-of-defaultcellstyle/50214920#50214920) for a few hints!

Answer (score 0):

I found what you need in this other answer:

[How do I change the datagridview selected row background color?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3178421/how-do-i-change-the-datagridview-selected-row-background-color/12801954)

```
dataGridView1.DefaultCellStyle.SelectionBackColor = Color.Blue;
dataGridView1.DefaultCellStyle.SelectionForeColor = Color.Red;
```

Comment: But doing `dataGridView1.DefaultCellStyle.SelectionForeColor = Color.Red;` will change all selected cells forecolor to red. Some of those cells might have to have blue text, not red.

I know I can change the default forecolor for a selected cell, but what I need is to not change it at all... The backcolor can change, but the forecolor must remain the same as it was before selecting the cell.

Comment: Sure, you can select the forecolor to match control color, I believe is called "control", that way, you can select any cell and the selection will not change. Makes sense?

Comment: I just re-read your text, then you need color.transparent in forecolor, that way is maintained the way it is, just make sure you backcolor has a good contrast to the cell's forecolor.

Comment: I just tried `Color.Transparent` and it made the forecolor literally transparent i.e. the same color as the backcolor, thus impossible to read. I have set my table to full row selection. In the same row, I have both blue and red text cells. I'm very afraid that is not possible to have a selected row with different forecolor cells.

Answer (score 0):

According to your problem, you would like to keep the cell forecolor when you change the

backcolor of the selected row.

You can try the following code.

```
 private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DataTable table = new DataTable();
            table.Columns.Add("Name");
            table.Columns.Add("Age");
            table.Columns.Add("Id");
            table.Rows.Add("test1", 22, 1001);
            table.Rows.Add("test2", 23, 1002);
            table.Rows.Add("test3", 24, 1003);
            dataGridView1.DataSource = table;
            dataGridView1.Rows[1].Cells[1].Style.ForeColor = Color.Yellow;
            dataGridView1.Rows[1].Cells[2].Style.ForeColor = Color.Yellow;
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            dataGridView1.CurrentRow.DefaultCellStyle.SelectionBackColor = Color.Green;
            var result = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells;
            foreach (DataGridViewCell item in result)
            {
                if (item.Style.ForeColor ==Color.Empty)
                {
                    item.Style.ForeColor = Color.Blue;
                }
            }

        }
```

Tested result:

[image]

You can see that in the second row, the yellow cells's forecolor hasn't been changed and its backcolor has been changed